# requirejs , multipage , weird order of execution

Tags: requirejs

I am using requirejs for a multipage application. I am having a weird issue with the order of execution of the main files. Here is my setup.

In all of my html pages ( This main has all the common js files that are required by all my pages)

then on each page (say page1.html):

```
<script data-main="main" src="require.js" />
<script>
require(['require','main'],function(require) {
      require(['main-library']);
});
</script>
```

My main.js looks like:

```
require.config({ 
    paths:{
        'lib':'../lib',
        'jquery': '../lib/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min',
        'jquery.iframe-transport' : '../lib/jquery.iframe-transport.min.js'
    },
    deps:['jquery','jquery-ui'],
    shim: {
         <other shim files>
    },
});  

require([<list of all other dependencies>], function() {
});
```

And the main-library.js looks like:

```
define('main-library',
    ['main',
    'jquery.iframe-transport',
     <other dependencies>
    ], 
    function() {
    }
);
```

My expectation:
Was that the "main-library" will not start to load until the "main" and all the dependencies specified in the main are not loaded. I expect this since I require "main-library" in a nested require call on each page. see above.

The issue:
When my page1.html loads, it looks like the main-library.js starts loading even before the main.js has finished loading and main-library fails to get the require.config and hence the paths for the dependencies are not seen by it.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. It was infact another require down in that page1.html that was loading the "main-library" again. So I had something like:

```
<script data-main="main" src="require.js" />
<script>
require(['require','main'],function(require) {
   require(['main-library']);
});
</script>
... 
... Other html ...
...
<script>
require(['main-library'],function(require) {
   //do something. 
});
</script>
```

This second require on main-library was the one that was failing to find the paths. Wrapping it with a require on main worked.

Comment: You can now follow the project from James which shows how you can go about this. I think my approach was similar what James explains, but ofcourse he is the author of requirejs :) [example-multipage](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage)